# Regex mach letters inside statement to make a word

Tags: java, regex

So I am trying to write a java program that will match (example : `eat`) in the string

```
asdasdjhaskldhlasdklsadeaadsasdkljhasdklhjt
```

So what would happen is

```
asdasdjhaskldhlasdklsad_**E**__**A**_adsasdkljhasdklhj_**T**_
```

So what i have got so far in regex is matching the first letter...

```
^([e]+) - E
```

But I so not know how to allow letters and spaces between the matches.

Comment: You might wanna start with a [regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). It's really quite simple: `e.*a.*t`.

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this:

```
e.*?a.*?t
```

This will match the closest `e`, `a` and `t` from the input string (which you highlighted).

Or you might use a negated class which might be faster on larger strings:

```
e[^a]*a[^t]*t
```

`[^a]*` will match anything but `a` and `[^t]*` will match anything but `t`.

Comment: I used ^(e)+.*?a.*?t and it matched everything like 
eeeeeaaaattttt

Comment: @user2821370 `^` matches the beginning of the string you're applying the regex to. `( ... )` is a capture group and you're repeating the `e` one or more times. Is there perhaps something else you need help with?

Comment: I want to match the first occurrence of a letter(s) in a string

Comment: @user2821370 Then use the regex I have provided you with. Don't use `^` or `(e)+`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pattern like this:

```
e.*a.*t
```

This will match an `e`, followed by zero or more of any characters, followed by an `a`, followed by zero or more of any characters, followed by a `t`.